# Know user logged in to Trac project in ITicketChangeListener

Tags: trac

i have a plugin in Trac project who send notifications emails when ticket action changed (created, closed, ...)

i want to know the user logged in to Trac to know if i must send or not my notification email.

For Example : i'm a logged in user, i will accept a ticket, so :

- the reporter receive notification mail (ok for me)
- the owner receive notification mail (ok for me)
- i don't want to receive mail (i must know the logged in trac user)

this is my code :

```
class TicketPostCreateOrUpdateActions(Component):

    implements(ITicketChangeListener)

    def ticket_changed(self, ticket, comment, author, old_values):
        _onw_wsdl = SOAPpy.SOAPProxy("http://xxxxxxxx")

        # cas fermeture ou réouverture d'un ticket
        if old_values.has_key('status')==1 and old_values['status'] is not ticket['status'] and ticket['reporter'] != ticket['owner']:
            _onw_wsdl.TracTicketStatusChanged(ticket.id, ticket['reporter'], ticket['summary'], ticket['milestone'], ticket['status'])
        elif old_values.has_key('owner')==1 and old_values['owner'] is not ticket['owner']:
                _onw_wsdl.TracTicketReassignationChanged(ticket.id, ticket['owner'], ticket['summary'], ticket['priority'], ticket['description'], 're-affectation')
         elif comment:
             _onw_wsdl.TracTicketCommentModified(ticket.id, ticket['owner'], ticket['reporter'], ticket['summary'], comment)
```

thanks for your help

Comment: `author` is the user who initiated the ticket change, so `author` is the user logged-in to Trac.

Comment: oh it was just in front of me !! thank you very much !